# Open Symmetric Key With Password In Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, encryption

I am trying to write a stored procedure to decrypt some data encrypted by a Symmetric Key that's encrypted with an Asymmetric Key with a password.

`OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY` requires a string literal for the password so I had to do a work around with `EXEC sp_executesql`. Is there a better way to do this?

```
DECLARE @open nvarchar(200), @close nvarchar(200)
SET @open = 'OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY skey DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY akey WITH PASSWORD = ' + quotename(@password,'''') + ';';
SET @close = 'CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY skey;';

EXEC sp_executesql @open

SELECT [TransactionID],Convert(varchar(max),DECRYPTBYKEY([EncryptedText])) as DecryptedText FROM [dbo].[TestTable];

EXEC sp_executesql @close
```

If you execute it with the wrong password it throws up the following errors:

```
Msg 15466, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
An error occurred during decryption.
Msg 15315, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The key 'skey' is not open. Please open the key before using it.
```

Should I just wrap `EXEC sp_executesql @open` in a `TRY ... CATCH` and return `NULL` or is there a (more) elegant way of handling this?

**EDIT:** What's the best way to handle someone calling this procedure with an incorrect password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EXAMPLE** of using keys, check your data and code:

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY akey WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_2048 
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'aaa123'
GO
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY skey WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256 ENCRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY akey
GO

DECLARE @t TABLE(plain VARCHAR(100), ciphered VARBINARY(MAX), unciphered VARCHAR(100))

INSERT @t(plain)
VALUES('11111'), ('22222'), ('33333')

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY skey DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY akey WITH PASSWORD = 'aaa123'

UPDATE @t SET Ciphered = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('skey'), plain)


UPDATE @t SET unciphered = CAST(DECRYPTBYKEY(ciphered) AS VARCHAR)

SELECT * FROM @t

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY skey
DROP SYMMETRIC KEY skey
DROP ASYMMETRIC KEY akey
```

**For proper logging** of wrong password decryption attempts try the following example, play with variable `@password`:

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY akey WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_2048 
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'aaa123'
GO
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY skey WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256 ENCRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY akey
GO

DECLARE @t TABLE(plain VARCHAR(100), ciphered VARBINARY(MAX), unciphered VARCHAR(100))

INSERT @t(plain)
VALUES('11111'), ('22222'), ('33333')

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY skey DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY akey WITH PASSWORD = 'aaa123'

UPDATE @t SET Ciphered = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('skey'), plain)
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY skey

DECLARE @open nvarchar(200), @close nvarchar(200), @password VARCHAR(20) = 'aaa123x'
SET @open = 'OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY skey DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY akey WITH PASSWORD = ' + quotename(@password,'''') + ';';
SET @close = 'CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY skey;';
BEGIN TRY 
  EXEC sp_executesql @open
  UPDATE @t SET unciphered = CAST(DECRYPTBYKEY(ciphered) AS VARCHAR)
  SELECT * FROM @t
  EXEC sp_executesql @close
END TRY BEGIN CATCH 
  SELECT 'Do whatever you want to do here with this caller. Suspicious caller: '+SUSER_SNAME()+', at: '+CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR)
END CATCH

DROP SYMMETRIC KEY skey
DROP ASYMMETRIC KEY akey
```

Comment: Any ideas about how to better protect against SQL injection while using this method?

Comment: As usual - since you cannot pass the password as parameter, use custom password-string checking, and run the statement under user, that have only one access right - to read and decrypt the particular column from particular table

Comment: Check your data and code - see attached example of using keys, as far as i know - the error Msg 15466, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 An error occurred during decryption. - means that you use wrong password

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware, my question is about how to best handle that specific scenario. Sorry for not making that clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[EncryptAndSaveValues]
@Value as varchar(100),
@EnKey as varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

set nocount on

Declare @sql nvarchar(1000)

set @sql='
Create Symmetric Key SymmetricKeyforPortal

With algorithm=desx

Encryption by password=N'''+@EnKey+''''

--print @sql

exec sp_executesql @sql

set nocount off
end
```

https://forums.asp.net/t/1348389.aspx?Declaring+Symmetric+Key+in+Stored+procedure